# Special Character show up in SSIS

Tags: sql, postgresql, ssis

I transfer data from Postgre to SQL Server using SSIS. and somehow the result is not the same like the source, There is special character between code.

```
Source data in Postgre CL019-B-1003MIN01
Destination data in SQL CL019-B-1003�MIN01
```

Can you guys have a clue about this ?

Thanks

Comment: Is that a single field in Postgresql? Or is that a row?

Comment: its row data, i dont have problem with other, just view record get error

Comment: Can you add to the question a screen shot showing the source table structure and from ssis the a shot of the preview of the data from the source editor